# How to show or hide button according to the length of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show or hide a button according to the length of an array.

Tried Doing conditional statement

```
var bios = [
    {
         id: 1,
         biography: "I am human",
    }
];

function addBio(bio) {
    if (bios.length === 0) {
        bios.push(bio);
        appendToBioTable(bio);
        $('bioHead').append(`<button id="bioButton">button</button>`)
    }
    else if (bios.length > 0) {
        $('#bioButton').remove();
    }
}
```

I need to show or remove the button instantly according to the size of an array.

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: well, i am sorry put only a part of my code now it is there

Answer (score 0):

When you append the button to the dom, you give it an `id` of "button", but when you go to remove it you are looking for an element with the `id` of "bioButton".

So simply change `$('#bioButton').remove();` to `$('#button').remove();`

Answer (score -1):

Here a working example, the button will appear only if the array is empty :

```js
var bios = [];

if (bios.length === 0) {
  $('#bioHead').append(`<button id="bioButo">button</button>`)
} else if (bios.length > 0) {
  $('#bioButton').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bioHead"></div>
```

Comment: No it won't, it will always be empty regardless in this example because you are creating a button with id `bioButo` but trying to remove one with id `bioButton`

Comment: The question was "how to show or hide a button according to the length of an array ?", my snippet do exactly that. I don't get your point @IsaacVidrine ?